# Boot Camp 5 drivers not installing on Windows 8 (iMac)

Tags: imac, bootcamp, windows

So I have a mid-2010 iMac 22" that I just installed Windows 8 on, but cannot get the Boot Camp 5 drivers to install.

I was unaware that my mid-2010 iMac was technically unsupported for the Windows 8, but the Boot Camp assistant native to my OSX successfully installed it anyways. I know that the Apple support pages say that it is unsupported but when I look at what the specs are needed to run Windows 8 (on the Windows 8 support pages) my machine qualifies.

I haven't done much with the Windows partition as of yet, but so far it seems to run fine. So my question is:

1. Is it possible for me to not install any drivers, and safely use the Windows 8?

or

1. Can we work around the "Boot Camp 5 isn't supported on this Mac" and install the Boot Camp 5 drivers?

Comment: Your machine has the technical specifications to run Windows 8, but it lacks the driver support from Apple. That's what they meant that windows 8 isn't supported.

Answer (score -2):

They don't support it because they want you to use their software